# How to solve "Unexpected error from external database driver" (followed by Chinese characters) while exporting huge excel data in SQL

Tags: sql, excel, import, odbc, oledb

When I try to import data from excel file in to SQL Database, I am getting error like:

> Unexpected error from external database driver (霰呫潈ూŐీL).

My code:

```
private void Import(string fileFullPath, string fileName, StreamWriter writer)
{
     string ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + fileFullPath +
    ";Extended Properties=" + (char)34 + "Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;" + (char)34;

    using (OleDbConnection cn = new OleDbConnection(ConnectionString))
    {
        cn.Open();
        DataTable dbSchema = cn.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);
        if (dbSchema == null || dbSchema.Rows.Count < 1)
        {
            writer.WriteLine("Error: Could not determine the name.");
            throw new Exception("Error: Could not determine the name.");
        }

        if (dbSchema.Rows.Count > 0)
        {

            Hashtable objHashTableOptionPool = new Hashtable();

            foreach (DataRow objDataRow in dbSchema.Rows)
            {
                if (objDataRow["TABLE_NAME"].ToString() != "Participants$")
                {
                    string name = objDataRow["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();

                    string checkname = string.Empty;
                    if (name.Substring((name.Length - 1), 1) == "'")
                    {
                        checkname = name.Substring(0, (name.Length - 1));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        checkname = name;
                    }
                    string Rname = name.Substring((checkname.Length - 1), 1);
                    if (Rname != "$")
                    {
                        continue;
                    }

                    OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [" + name + "]", cn);
                    DataTable dt = new DataTable(name);
                    da.Fill(dt); //getting error here

                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Getting error while filling the data table with data adapter.

Comment: Check your ODBC driver poperties.OLEDB Provider for ODBC may not be available.Download it and install.

Comment: Is that C# or some other language?

Comment: Yes.. it is C# language

Comment: Sure Athul. But i can import data using the same oledb provider in other places. I Hope no issue with provider.

Comment: @NithyaShree:try this using JET provider.. http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/682470/How-to-solve-Unexpected-error-from-external-databa

Comment: @Athul.. Getting same error.

Comment: @NithyaShree: are you trying to import data from xls(Excel 2007 or Excel 2010 Files) or xlsx,? add IMEX=1 in connection string and try.

Comment: Thanks @Athul.. The issue is from the excel file while i tried to upload. The columns were overlapped each other.